# iOS Swift Navigation Bar Buttons Shift Down

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uialertview

I use the following code to add a navigation bar with buttons to my view:

```
let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, screenWidth, 44))
var homeButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: controller, action: "closeView")
homeButton.image = UIImage(named: "back.png")
var item = UINavigationItem(title: title)
item.leftBarButtonItem = homeButton
if addPlus {
    var addButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: controller, action: "addItem")
    addButton.image = UIImage(named: "plus-25.png")
    item.rightBarButtonItems = [addButton]
}



var items = [
    item
]


navBar.setItems(items, animated: true)

controller.view.addSubview(navBar)
```

For some reason when any type of UIAlertView is displayed the buttons on the bar shift down.

[image: Screen shot of problem]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Did you include the view in a Navigationcontroller?

Comment: Same for me.  It only happens with my right bar button items, which I use code to create (i.e. setRightBarButtonItems in viewDidLoad).  The left bar button item does not shift down and that one was created using interface builder.  So it appears to have something to do with custom bar button items.

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, bring a navigation bar and make it to be auto-fitted in the screen, and don't try shifting it down.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but since this behavior was only happening with my custom bar button items (and not the bar button items I made using interface builder) I just removed them with "self.navBarNavItem.setRightBarButtonItems([], animated: true)" before calling "presentViewController".

Then if the result of the alert (i.e. what the user selected) resulted in staying on the current view (instead of changing views) then I add them back in when that handler is executed.

This stopped the buttons from visibly showing in the wrong position and then put them back in the correct position when the alert completed.